# Zend: How to insert NULL values into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, null, zend-db

I am using Zend Framework with MySQL,Apache and Ubuntu 9.04.

I am trying to insert NULL values into database like this:

```
$personObj->setPersonId( '1' );
$personObj->setPersonEmail('NULL');
$personObj->save();
```

But 'NULL' is stored in database as string and not *NULL*.

When I use this:

```
$personObj->setPersonId( '1' );
$personObj->setPersonEmail(NULL);
$personObj->save();
```

But nothing happens and previous entry is unchanged.

What should I do to insert NULL values into MySQL?

Comment: When I use $personObj->setPersonEmail('NULL'); It inserts NULL as string. When I use $personObj->setPersonEmail(NULL); previous entry is unchanged and nothing happens.

Comment: What type of object is `$personObj`? As others already said, without knowing the implementation of `setPersonEmail()` you cannot determine what has to be passed in.

Comment: $personObj is person's record object. setPersonEmail() is a mothod to set the value for personEmail entry in database. save() is a method to store all set values into database.It is a common practice in zend framework. As I said that it is working for String values perfectly but problem is NULL entry.

Comment: That does not help... It's crucial to know the implementation `setPersonEmail()` and `save()`; especially important is how the data is written to the database. A lot of things can happen in between calling `save()` and the time when the data is written to the database.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are not modifying any of the values after they are assigned then

```
new $personObj->setPersonEmail(new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL'));
```

Comment: This worked for me too, but I have to do `new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL')`

Answer (score 1):

First thought would be straight passing in the null keyword, without quotes around it.  As pavium said, the quotes around it turn it into a string.

Comment: I have tried this $personObj->setPersonEmail(null); But no luck. Actually I am updating this entry. An email is already exists in database and I want to remove this and insert NULL.

Comment: Could try empty quotes, though that would likely just make it an empty string. 

Have you tried accessing the column more directly, rather than through the set function? ie:
$personObj->personEmail = null;

Answer (score 0):

I think putting NULL in quotes is what makes it look like a string.

I don't know about your method, but for a direct insert though a `mysql` INSERT command, the single quotes around a NULL are incorrect.

Comment: I have also tried this $personObj->setPersonEmail(NULL); But nothing happened. Previous entry is unchanged.

Comment: It depends **entirely** on how the `setPersonEmail()` method works, then, and whether it is valid for *updating* an entry.

Comment: Yes it updates. When I use this $personObj->setPersonEmail('test@test.com'); It replace previous database entry with test@test.com. But my problem is to remove previous entry and insert NULL if an user remove his/her email address.